# CCK field with multiple fields inside

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cck

im new on drupal and im having a problem with CCK fields.

I made a custom cck field and the install schema its like this:

```
function usig_location_field_schema($field) {
  return array(
    'columns' => array(
      'location_cck_usig' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
         'length' => 255,
         'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'lat_cck_usig' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
         'length' => 255,
         'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
      'lon_cck_usig' => array(
        'type' => 'varchar',
         'length' => 255,
         'not null' => FALSE,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

But when i save the new content .. drupal crash with this log :

> Fatal error:  Cannot create references to/from string offsets nor
>   overloaded objects in /includes/common.inc on line 6392

So .. i know that im  doing something wrong. I just dont know which hook use to save the fields.. (its possible save various fields at once ?)

Thx for all and sry for my english

Answer (score 1):

You can always use this great module called [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection)

Cheers